# How does queue works internally for multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

From [the python official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), I got below sample code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

It seems like the queue variable is shared beween parent and child process. Below is the code with some modification for the address of queue.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def f(q):
    data = [42, None, "hello"]
    q.put(data)
    print("q in child process: ", id(q))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    print("q in parent process: ", id(q))
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())  # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

The address was not same. I want to know how the queue is shared between two processes.

Comment: It may be platform-dependent. I think different systems have different mechanisms for inter-process communication.

Comment: I haven't looked through the details, but generally. operating systems implement sharable objects like named pipes and semaphores. Multiprocessing [pickles](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) objects to send between processes. The `Queue` is written to create operating system shared objects, pickle a reference to those objects, and then build the connection when it is recreated in the other process. The two processes have separate instances of the Queue object that internally hold their own "end" of the shared operating system objects.

Comment: A Queue is built on top of `multiprocessing.Pipe` instances and its `multiprocessing.connection.Connection` instances. The source can be found in your installation's `Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py` file.